# jquery display submenu while hovering

Tags: jquery, submenu

I have a horizontal menu. This submenu is displayed outside the ul. When i hover en specific class (for example .p_over), I want the .submenu-div to appaer. When I hover the .submenu-div, I want it to be still there. However, when moving my mouse frome .p_over to the .submenu-div, it dissappears.

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li id="li_arrow_right" class="p_over"><a href="pages/over.php">Over <span>&#59230;</span></a></li>
        <li id="li_arrow_right" class="p_projecten"><a href="pages/projecten.php">Onze projecten<span>&#59230;</span></a></li>
        <li id="li_arrow_right" class="p_nieuws"><a href="pages/nieuws.php">Nieuws<span>&#59230;</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span id="link_search"><a href="#">&#128269;</a></span>
    <div class="btn_small" id="btn_arrow_right">Vragenlijsten<span>&#59230;</span></div>

    <div class="submenu">
        <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li id="li_arrow_right"><a href="over.php">Wie zijn wij?<span>&#59230;</span></a></li>
            <li id="li_arrow_right"><a href="projecten.php">Wat bieden wij?<span>&#59230;</span></a></li>
            <li id="li_arrow_right"><a href="nieuws.php">Wie bent u?<span>&#59230;</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.p_over').hover(function(){
    $('.submenu').slideDown(50);        
},
function(){
    $('.submenu').slideUp(50);          
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: easiest way would be to restructure the html so that each submenu is inside of it's parent, but give be a second I'll write a way to do it without restructuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `slideUp` function inside of a `setTimeout` so that inside of the submenu you can clear the timeout (and stop the `slideUp`) if it is hovered over. If you want to allow more time for the user to get to the submenu before it disappears, just change the `250` in the second from last line. This is amount of time in milliseconds. At this point all you would have to do is position the submenu accordingly to the menu.

Here is a really rough [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc9cf/1/)

```
var t;
$('.p_over, .submenu').on('mouseenter', function(){
    if(t){
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = false;
    }
    $('.submenu').slideDown(50);
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.submenu').slideUp(50);
    }, 250);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I am just a beginner with jquery. Your right by saying that I should have set my submenus in the menu's li's. Thanks!

Comment: however, when i hover from the submenu back to the li, the submenu dissapears.

Comment: this problem occurs only when i apply the jquery to multiples li's

Comment: Can you show me the code for the page or do a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? it might just be that the li isn't filling the whole a element that you're hovering over